# How to let Google's crawler know about new Atom/RSS updates?

Tags: seo, sitemap, googlebot, rss

What is the right way of letting Google's crawler know about new  Atom/RSS updates?

The documentation about sitemap is clear about how to ping the crawler, but when it comes to  Atom/RSS, there is only a vague reference to PubSubHubbub in their docs [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/best-practices-for-xml-sitemaps-rssatom.html):

> In order for Google to not miss updates, the RSS/Atom feed should have
>   all updates in it since at least the last time Google downloaded it.
>   The best way to achieve this is by using PubSubHubbub. The hub will
>   propagate the content of your feed to all interested parties (RSS
>   readers, search engines, etc.) in the fastest and most efficient way
>   possible.

How can I ping PubSubHubbub? Is sending post requests to `https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com` the official way of letting Google know about these updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official way of letting Google know of your updates is your sitemap.

Submitting your Google Site's sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools

> ```
> On your Webmaster Tools home page, select your site.
> In the left sidebar, click Site configuration and then Sitemaps.
> Click the Add/Test Sitemap button in the top right.
> Enter /system/feeds/sitemap into the text box that appears.
> Click Submit Sitemap.
> ```

You will need to change system/feeds/sitemap to the URL for your RSS. You will not need to add the `http://sitename.domain/`

Here's the link for Google Webmaster Tools:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

And for Bing and Yahoo:
https://www.bing.com/webmaster/

Comment: From google documents, I got the impression that sitemaps are or archived and historical pages, and feeds are for realtime updates. is this not correct? Also, if the feeds can be fed to google sitemaps, what's the use of PubSubHubBub?

Comment: The XML sitemaps will give Google information about all of the pages on your site while the RSS/Atom feeds will provide all updates on your site, helping Google to keep your content fresher in its index.  This will save your site from lazy pings and will let the search engines have a better overall view of your data.   That said others who use your PubSubHubBub can subscribe to your data and when you change the data the hub can push the changes out to the subscriber vs a subscriber requesting a change.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your corrections and updates in your feed atom.
2. Then create a new id tag and date update with this tool http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=atomidtimestamp
3. Insert the data to your refresh atom feed. 
   Example: 
   [tag:movies-news-mob.com,2014-10-21:/manga/video/db-1/20141021132432369]
   [2014-10-21T15:24:32-02:00]
4. Publish your feed atom in the network.
5. Check your feed atom with this tool http://feedvalidator.org/
6. Reporting about this Feedburner (Google Service).
   Hope this helps